# Error while making a simple two button game on Python IDLE 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a basic game in which there are two buttons 'left' and 'right' and I have a character. The character should move left and right when the respective buttons are clicked. This is the code I have used. This code is not giving the desired output. Please, can you tell me how to put the two buttons in one area? Also can you please help make this code more efficient?

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(a, master):
        super(Application, a).__init__(master)
        a.grid()
        a.b_c = 0
        a.b = Button(a)
        a.b['text'] = "START"
        a.b['command'] = a.u
        a.b.grid()


    def u(a):
        a.b['text'] = "Move Right"
        a.b_c += 1
        print("\n"*40+" "*a.b_c+"*")

root = Tk()
root.title("Bot World")

app = Application(root)


class Applicatio(Frame):

    def __init__(x, master):
        super(Applicatio, x).__init__(master)
        x.grid()
        x.b_c = 0
        x.b = Button(x)
        x.b['text'] = "START"
        x.b['command'] = x.u
        x.b.grid()


    def u(x):
        x.b['text'] = "Move Left"
        a.b_c -= 1
        print("\n"*40+" "*a.b_c+"*")

root = Tk()
root.title("Bot World")

app = Applicatio(root)
```

Comment: You seem to have posted the same code twice. Was that your intention? In a tkinter application  you should aways have exactly one instance of `Tk` running.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. Your naming convention makes it hard to read what you are trying to accomplish. You are using an outdated super() method and for some reason have chosen to not use `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was a bit hard to follow. Please work on your naming style. PEP8 style guidelines will help here and it will make it easier for others to read your code.

Keep in mind for Python 3 all you need to do with super is `super().__init__()`.

99.9% of the time you only ever need one `Tk()` instance.

Instead of trying to create 2 separate classes for your buttons you can combine it into one class and it will be easier to manage the `b_c` class attribute.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.b_c = 0
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="START", command=self.set_buttons)
        self.btn1.pack()

    def set_buttons(self):
        self.btn1.config(text="Move Right", command=self.move_right)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Move Left", command=self.move_left)
        self.btn2.pack()

    def move_right(self):
        self.b_c += 1
        print("\n" * 40 + " " * self.b_c + "*")

    def move_left(self):
        self.b_c -= 1
        print("\n" * 40 + " " * self.b_c + "*")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bot World")
Application(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```